# Strategy involving database reloading in JSF app with i18n

Tags: jsf-2, internationalization, primefaces

I am developing a web application with **PrimeFaces/JSF**.

It has the typical combo for **language selection**.

When someone hits the combo, a **valueChangeListener** is fired.

That listener (changeLocaleListener) changes the viewPort Locale, so the proper message bundle .properties file could be loaded.

This works OK as expected, **BUT**, I am confused about the strategy to adopt in order to load again from database the actual contents of the page that depends on i18n.

I mean, how do yo do to refresh the page calling the proper actionListeners method.

Imagine the following scenario:

1. You arrive the home page (Spanish is selected as default language).
2. A list of latest news and latest events are displayed (in Spanish).
3. You click in one of the news and arrive to the detailed new page (in Spanish).
4. Yo select the English language in the combo, and then, the detailed info of the selected new should be reloaded from database and displayed in English.

Is there a way to automatize that and control what dao methods should be invoked according with the actual page the user is in?

```
<p:selectOneMenu 
    value="#{i18nCtrl.mdl.local}" 
    var="loc"
    onchange="$('#form').submit()" 
    converter="localConverter" 
    valueChangeListener="#{i18nCtrl.changeLocaleListener}" >
    ...
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you just give current URL to POJO and do redirect from it?

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit the solution? I know about viewRoot.getViewId() to get the actual page url, but I dont know exactly how to do the thing

Comment: I am new with this. I think someone smarter should give advice. But if you can get page url and changed language, I just do same select data, which you do showing this Spanish page, from DB according to new lang. But I think, there are better ways to do this, which I would like to know too.

Comment: BalusC feedback needed here :-/